# setTimeout is overwriting my code on third call

Tags: javascript, debugging

I wrote a function that replaces a HTML string, the problem is as follow:

```
function omniText(answer1, answer2, answer3, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("goodAnswer").innerHTML = answer1,
        document.getElementById("mildAnswer").innerHTML = answer2,
        document.getElementById("badAnswer").innerHTML = answer3;

    }, timeout);
```

I call it three times in three different functions. When I call it the third time, my string appears but is then replaced by the previous one.

Ex:

```
//will show 123 in html page
function show123() {
  omniText("123", "", "", 1500)
}
show123();

//will show Hello in html page
function showHello() {
  omniText("Hello", "", "", 4500)
}
showHello();

//will show Bye but then will show 123
function showBye() {
  omniText("Bye", "", "", 2500)
}
showBye();
```

Comment: They're showing the strings in the order of the timeouts. `4500` runs after `2500` and overwrites it.

Comment: What are you expecting instead? Are you expecting the `showHello()` timeout to start after the `show123()` timeout completes?

Comment: @Barmar I have another function with a timer. Basically one waits for the other to respond as I am using a typewriter script.

Comment: Have the functions return a promise that resolves when the timeout completes, and then call the next function in its `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

playing around with timeouts is not the best move, `Promise` is there to help you, as you will know exactly when something is done or not, for example, if your main method returns a promise

```js
function omniText(answer1, answer2, answer3, timeout) {
  // let's return a new Promise
  // all you need is to call resolve() or reject(new Error(...))
  // to tell when it's done, or there's an issue
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // your main code
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("goodAnswer").innerHTML = answer1,
      document.getElementById("mildAnswer").innerHTML = answer2,
      document.getElementById("badAnswer").innerHTML = answers;

      // we're done, so let's call resolve()
      resolve();

    }, timeout);
  })
}
```

if you need an intermediary call, just simply return

```js
function show123() {
  return omniText("123", "", "", 1500)
}

function showHello() {
  return omniText("Hello", "", "", 4500)
}

function showBye() {
  return omniText("Bye", "", "", 2500)
}
```

and either call like spaghetti hell

```js
(function() {
  show123()
    .then(function() { return showHello(); })
    .then(function() { return showBye(); })
})()
```

or using `async/await`

```js
(async () => {
  await show123()
  await showHello()
  await showBye()
})()
```

---

working example:

```js
// main function
const omniText = (answer1, answer2, answer3, timeout) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(answer1)
      resolve()
    }, timeout)
  });

// intermidiate calls
const show123 = () => omniText("123", "", "", 1500);
const showHello = () => omniText("Hello", "", "", 4500);
const showBye = () => omniText("Bye", "", "", 2500);

// result
(async () => {
  console.log('START');

  await show123();
  await showHello();
  await showBye();

  console.log('END');
})()
```